# I cannot use Kal Calendar in my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am using Kal calendar from http://github.com/klazuka/Kal. I want to use this calendar on my app, so I added the "Kal" folder to my project, and added the following code:

```
KalViewController *calendar = [[[KalViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:calendar animated:YES];
```

This is my code:

```
#import "kalViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    KalViewController *calendar = [[[KalViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:calendar animated:YES];    
}
```

Nothing happens. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Momeks nice to see you Integrated kal..  my project is on desktop. and my downloaded file from the link  http://github.com/klazuka/Kal is saved on desktop..... i followed all the steps...  In step 6,,,  Add the relative path from your project's directory to the "Kal/src" directory  i dont know how to add relative path .. can you tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure navigationController is not nil and it is being initialized as the root view controller of your UINavigationController? If not, you can't use pushViewController until you do that!

Try

```
[self presentModalViewController:calendar animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

If `self.navigationController` is nil, nothing will happen. (Method calls to nil are noops.) Ensure that you actually have a navigationController.

Comment: i have a navigationbar and controller ,still doesn't any happen